# Inputs on methods for developing a VoIP application in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, voip

I'm developing a VoIP app where I want to stream audio captured from the microphone as Data to the server. From the server side I want to send the Data out to all the participants in the conversation.

My first thought is to use AVAudioEngine and then install a tap on the microphone, convert the AVAudioPCMBuffer to Data and then use the Alamofire framework
`Alamofire.upload(data: Data, to: URLConvertible)` method to upload each audio frame and then sending this out to all the clients. This comes with some complications though on the client side, like establishing the connection and so on. It feels like with this solution I need to send out thousands of messages from the server all the time saying "more packages are now available".

Anyone out there that can shed some light or input on good solutions around this? Or is this actually a good way to go?

Any help, input or thought is very much appreciated.

Comment: You will probably want to use a UDP stream. Research RTSP

Comment: I'm currently trying to do it with socket streams, will post about my progress.

Comment: I worked it out using sockets (not websockets)